# get: unexpected URISyntaxException

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop

I am getting below error in the line where I trying to

`hadoop fs -get "$path" "$bpath"`

> get: unexpected URISyntaxException

Though when I print it - syntax looks perfect. Even when I copied it works fine.

Comment: Since we don't know how your variables are set, you should at least run ths command under `set -x` and copy&paste the trace output into your question.

Comment: What does `$path` and `$bpath` stand for?